# Following the naming convension, but my github project page still gives me a 404

Tags: git, github-pages

I have an origination called BigSense and I have the following repository for my presentations:

```
https://github.com/BigSense/presentations
```

It has a branch called `gh-pages` with just the generated code, but when I attempt to access a page within it:

```
http://bigsense.github.io/presentations/scala.html
```

I get a 404. I've read through the help pages multiple times and I seem to be following all the correct naming conventions. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to create an organization repo first.
Once http://bigsense.github.io/ is working, the presentation will also be accessible.

Here is the [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/):

> User & Organization Pages live in a special repository dedicated to
>   GitHub Pages files. You will need to name this repository with the
>   account name, e.g. atmos/atmos.github.io.
>
> You must use the username.github.io naming scheme. Content from the
>   master branch will be used to build and publish your GitHub Pages
>   site. You can only use your own account name for a User or
>   Organization Page repository. A repository like joe/bob.github.io will
>   not build a User Pages site.
>
> When User Pages are built, they are available at
>   http(s)://.github.io.

Comment: I tried to make my presentation that account to begin with; tried to create a new repo: https://github.com/BigSense/bigsense.github.io, added and index page and install get a 404 :(

Comment: Should work. Add an index.html to the repo and wait for 5/10 minutes. Then you should be able to access it.

Comment: ah, forgot to push bigsense.github.io after I create the index. Also it is required to have an index.html in the project's gh-pages branch as well. Got it working now. Thanks!